# How can you call JavaScript builtins from Perl 6 with the new JS backend?

Tags: javascript, raku, rakudo

I know it is possible to invoke Java when Perl 6 is using that backend: [How do I invoke a Java method from perl6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27156329/how-do-i-invoke-a-java-method-from-perl6)

Is there a way yet to access e.g. the JavaScript DOM interface from Perl 6 with the new Rakudo JavaScript VM running in the browser?

Perhaps something like this:

```
use v6;
use javascript::dom:from<JavaScript>;
```

Comment: The DOM APIs are not part of JavaScript; they're services exposed by web browsers. That said, it's possible that some sort of "virtual" DOM is available for doing things like screen scraping.

Comment: Yes, and I would expect that the DOM API could be made available to Perl 6 running on JavaScript in the browser.

Comment: Note that "Java" and "JavaScript" are completely different, unrelated languages.

Comment: I know. Perl 6 can use them both as backend virtual machines. The three it supports are Moar, JVM and now JavaScript.

Comment: Oh OK. Well I don't see any mention of that in the Rakudo documentation, but it doesn't seem unlikely.

Comment: It is very new: http://blogs.perl.org/users/pawel_murias/2018/10/rakudojs-update---it-has-been-merged-into-master-plus-6pad-unveiling.html. I just heard about it today.

Comment: I've pinged Pawel Murias about this question.  I hope he'll be able to provide you with an answer in the next 24 hours or so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can now access the DOM using EVAL(:lang, 'return document')
See https://perl6.github.io/6pad/#4ee170f8043efe4802c8e6fb55d6a187 for an example.